# Combine values in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to iterate over 2 list of dictionaries in a single loop

This is what i got

```
a = [{'Date' : '123', 'amt' : '234'},{'Date' : '222','amt' : '458'}]
b = [{'Date' : '123', 'item' : '1'},{'Date' : '123', 'item' : '2'},{'Date' : '222', 'item' :'3'},{'Date' : '222', 'item' : '4'}]

txta = 'this is text a {Date} {amt}'
txtb = 'this is B {Date} {item}'


aa = [txta.format(**t) for t in a]
bb = [txtb.format(**z) for z in b]

data = aa+bb
print(data)
```

**Current Output**

```
['this is text a 123 234', 'this is text a 222 458', 'this is B 123 1', 'this is B 123 2', 'this is B 222 3', 'this is B 222 4']
```

**Required Output**

```
['''this is text a 123 234 ,this is B 123 1, this is B 123 2'''],['''this is text a 222 458, this is B 222 3, this is B 222 4''']
```

here the dictionary b's items are sorted in dictionary a where the key 'Date' is same .

Sorry if this is already asked, i did not get any.

Comment: So you want to iterate over the two lists of dictionaries on matching dates?

Comment: yes exactly .. i have given the output too . please help if you can

Comment: @DaniMesejo please answer if you know

Comment: The question is closed

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes i know, but i'm not an expert in python. im not able to understand from other threads. If you can answer then that would be a great favor.. Else thanks a lot :)